# Creating the database from the Entity Framework 0..1 to 1 is NOT NULL

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4.1

I just started with the Entity Framework and started to design the model first. So in my model there is a Person who can have a PrivateTelephone, so I created an 0..1 to 1 association. As the picture below shows.

[image]

So far so good. But when I generate the database the [PrivateTelephone] is set to `NOT NULL`. Why can't this be just `NULL`?

Comment: After the database generation, have you tried to change the field to NULL? If EF works after that, I would not think about it anymore.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham I was not allowed to do that, so I linked to an external picture hosting site. Thank you for changing it.

Comment: @Giedo: Oh, didn't know that.  That's lame!  YW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is becauser your relations are defined in reverse order. You should have 1 on `Person` and 0..1 on `Telecom` to specify that `Person` is the principal which can have one or zero phones. In your mapping you say that `Telecom` is principal which can have one or zero persons but person must have `Telecom`. It will also lead to reverse problem due to your incorrect mapping. You have six one-to-one relations to `Telecom` but if you reverse them as you demand you will say that all six relations (all six FKs in `Telecom`) will be NOT NULL = each record will have to participate in all six relations.

One-to-one relation is very special and should be used rarely. You should instead have one-to-many relation from `Person` to `Telecom` with a new column in `Telecom` specifying the type.

When using one-to-one relation you must have FK in dependent table configured with unique index. EF doesn't support unique indices so when you model one-to-one relation in model first it is still one-to-many in database and if database is used by another application it can break your application.

Also avoid unnecessary inheritance. Do you need `Person` as separate entity? = is there any instance which is only person and not employee? Are there more derived types from person? If not you don't need person and if yes it still doesn't mean that base person is a good idea. The same is true with employee. Inheritance has its own rules in EF and when using model first it will by default creates TPT inheritance = the worst one because it results in very complex and slow database queries.

Comment: Thank you for you fast reply. What I want to achieve is that a `Person`, `Employee` or `Company` can have one or more `Telecom`. But the types are limited. So you suggest to add a type to the telecom?

And I want the possibility to have only a `person`, `employee` or `User`. So I derived those from each other.

Comment: So you must handle types consistency in your application and not in the database. If you want to maintain consistency in your database you must completely change your model.

Comment: Sorry not the model - the approach. If you want to maintain consistency in the database you should use database first = design your database in the way to enforce your requirements and after that try to create entity model from that database. In model first you can start with some additional entity combining PersonId, TelecomId and "TypeId" in complex key and replace all thoese one-to-one relations with single one-to-many relation to this new entity.